# Python Use Switch Case?

Tags: python, switch-statement

Does Python implement `switch/case` at all or are python developers suppose to use a series of `if, elif, else` statements instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python does not implement a `switch`. An alternative is using a dict like so:

```
def func1():
    pass

def func2():
    pass

switch = {
    "do1": func1,
    "do2": func2,
}

do_str = "do1"
switch[do_str]()
```

Comment: Using dictionary is the elegant way, especially if you have "many" cases (whatever many could mean to you). For few choices, use the simpler if .. elif .. else construct. This is what Python documentation recommends: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html